# How to get an object from an Array with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express

I am trying to get a single object from an array in a mongoDB database.

The collection looks like this :

```json
[
  {
    _id: "60313c2de6ae000124b6626e",
    title: "<p>yyyyyyyyy</p>",
    description: "<p>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyaaaaaaaaaa</p>",
    authorId: "603000031f00ce4750e077ab",
    createDate: "2021-02-20T16:43:25.083+00:00",
    posts: [
      {
        _id: "95633628-a396-9621-7d4d-6ff5859f849c",
        title: "<p>sdfggfdsgdssgfd</p>",
        content: "",
        date: "2021-02-20T16:44:13.917Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have an express server set up with this route

```
app.get("/api/" + BLOGS_COLLECTION + "/:blogId" + "/post" + "/:postId", function (req, res) {
db.collection(BLOGS_COLLECTION).aggregate({ $match: { _id: req.params.postId } }, {
    $project: {
        posts: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$posts",
                as: "post",
                cond: { $elemMatch: ["$$post._id", req.params.postId] }
            }
        }
    }
}, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get post");
    } else {
        res.status(200).json(doc);
    }
});
});
```

But it returns this error :

```
(node:12780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: unknown top level operator: $match
```

Granted, it is the first time I do an express server with mangoDB as database, I can't make it work.

Can you help me ?

Comment: If you want to use `$match` and `$project` use aggregation instaead of findOne.

Comment: So I did try to use aggregate but the request never returns and is still pending. In the end, I just want to do a request that returns the object from the array in that collection. I just read you needed match and project to achieve that.

Comment: I did try to remove the $match operator but to no avail.

Comment: What you have there is a pipeline, `$filter` is not available in findOne.  Checkout the mongoose docs for [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate)

Comment: Thank you but I do not use Mongoose. I had an error because I had a ) before the function. But now, I get a cursor returning, how can I transform it in a json or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `$elemMatch` into a `$filter`, you can use `$eq` like this:

```
db.collection(BLOGS_COLLECTION).aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": req.params.postId
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "posts": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$posts",
          "as": "post",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$post._id",
              req.params.postId
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6ERBj3ziyh)